# Angular map. What is it?

Tags: angular, dictionary, filter

I am learning Angular 6 and I am puzzled with constructions like a:

```
this.contentArray.map((v: string, i: number) => `Content line ${i + 1}`)
```

or like a:

```
return this.aService.getItems()
    .pipe(map(response => response.data));
```

I am run through the couples of book like a "The_Complete_Book_on_Angular_6" or "Pro Angular 6" (Adam Freeman) but there are no simple explanations there. Google kept silence about that too. **Can someone give the right and good tutorial or may be book (for amateurs) about *array.map, array.filter* and about *.pipe(map(...))?***

Comment: It has nothing to do with angular. The array `map` is a javascript method, you can find more documentation about it in the MDN website. The pipable `map` is from RxJS, you can learn more about RxJS at https://learnrxjs.io.

Answer (score 11):

The first one is simply [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), while the second one is the `rxjs` [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator.

In the first case, you take an existing array and apply a function to each of its elements

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(x => x + 2) // [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

while the second case is essentialy the same thing in the world of observables.

> Applies a given project function to each value emitted by the source
>   Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.

Comment: Rxjs map can be applied to single value. It won't need to be array of objects

Answer (score 6):

In your first statement,
Map is JavaScript array function which iterates through each item of the array in order to map array of object to another array of object.

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5] ;
let result = array.map(val => val +10); //11,12,13,14,15
```

In your second statement, map is coming from rxjs library. This maps  object(s) to another but the resulting object  will be observable.

```
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); //add 10 to each value const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10)); //output: 11,12,13,14,15
```

Comment: Thans, so what goals for we use "v" in my example, if "v" doesnt use anymore in right part of expression: this.contentArray.map((v: string, i: number) => `Content line ${i + 1}`)   ?????

Comment: v is item, i is index of the array